# How to clean working directory after pipeline in Gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use gitlab-ci/cd pipeline for my project. All is fine, but after pipeline ended all files are continuing to exists in working directory of gitlab-runner until next time pipeline will be started.
Now I use "rm -rf ./*" to clean directory inside script, but I must care about files for artifacts. Is there any keyword or settings to clean working directory?

Answer (score 1):

The artifacts are stored by default on `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts` when the Job finishes.

If you just want to take care of not deleting them before they're actually attached; you can just create a `clean-up` stage which sole job is to delete everything within the directory.

```
stages:
 - build
 - clean

build_job_1:
 stage: build
 ...

build_job_2:
 stage: build
 ...

cleanup:
 stage: clean
 script:
  - rm -rf ./*
```

Comment: This approach only works, if the cleanup job is executed on the same machine as the build job. If you have multiple runners on different machines, it may fail.